# Owl Carousel по клику показывает последний слайд

Tags: owl-carousel

На сайте каталог товаров выводится с помощью Owl Slider. Выводится 4 товара в строчку. Проблема следующая: если нажимать на область в правом нижнем углу (произвольную область), то последний товар становится на первое место и все остальные товары исчезают. Не нашел описание такой функции среди стандартных, и сам тоже ничего такого не делал. Просто стандартное подключение. Попробовал подключить последнюю версию js файла - не помогло. Попробовал включить loop - проблема исчезает, но мне не подходит такое решение. Попробовал выключить mouseDrag - проблема исчезает, но как пользоваться слайдером, если не работает управление мышью? выключить touchDrag - проблема не исчезает. выключить pullDrag - проблема только усиливается, при клике справа как раз происходит переход последнего элемента на первое место и не показываются остальные элементы. выключить freeDrag - проблема не исчезает.  Поделитесь опытом, как победить эту проблему. Всем заранее спасибо! Пример подключения ниже:

```
$('.cameras-parent').owlCarousel({
dots:false,
margin: 40,
ignoreHiddenItems: true,
lazyLoad: true,
responsive:{
0: {
items: 1
  },
 800: {
items: 3
  } ,
  1400: {
  items: 4 
  }   
 }
});
```

Comment: А что у Вас в этой произвольной области? Проверьте в консоли браузера, и наличие ошибок тоже. Проверьте другие скрипты и стили, которые могут влиять на поведение слайдера.

Comment: В этой области ничего нет. Ошибок в консоли браузера тоже нет.